# php if NULL statement

Tags: php, drupal

How can I rewrite the statement below to be the opposite of NULL. The field has data

`field_sidebar_ourhistory[0]['value'] != NULL) : ?>
Display my test here`

Comment: What is the `opposite of NULL`? Is it `1`? Is it `true`? Is it `false`?

Comment: Note that when working with null, you might want to use === for comparison instead of ==. `false == null` and `0 == null` but `false !== null` and `0 !== null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isset() might do what you're looking for:

```
<?php

if (isset($field_sidebar_ourhistory[0]['value']))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!field_sidebar_ourhistory[0]['value'] != NULL)
{

}
```

"!" inverts whatever value is returned (true => false, false => true)